# Ignoring things before a particular symbol in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm kinda new to R, and I was wondering if there's a function that allows you to ignore things before a certain symbol. In particular, if I have a list of names: 
`James Brown, Kevin Hunter`, etc. I would like to take only last names, so if there's a function that allows me to ignore everything before space (for instance, for `James Brown`, there's space before `Brown`, so `James` will be ignored, and only `Brown` will be taken), then I could do it easily. Is there such function in R?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `?strsplit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `sub`:

```
s <- c("James Brown", "Kevin Hunter")

sub(".+ ", "", s)
# [1] "Brown"  "Hunter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches (one mlt already gace):

```
x <- c("James Brown", "Kevin Hunter")

sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 2)

library(qdap)
char2end(x)

## > sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 2)
## [1] "Brown"  "Hunter"

## > char2end(x)
## [1] "Brown"  "Hunter"
```